# C# MVC. Каким образом javascript объект преобразуется в серверный объект при вызове метода контроллера?

Tags: c#, mvc

[image: Пример кода]

В каком месте javascript объект преобразуется в серверный объект, и как в это можно вмешаться ?

Comment: Браузер отправляет запрос с JSON на сервер --> сервер смотрит на запрос, выбирает нужный контроллер и метод в нем, смотрит какие метод принимает параметры, использует привязки (bindings) чтобы переданный JSON сконвертировать в параметр метода, вызывает метод, получает результат и отправляет его обратно браузеру

Comment: @tym32167 Почему не в ответы? Укажите ещё, что преобразование из Json в строку для POST запроса делается в 28 строке, а контроллер делает преобразование из строки POST в класс внутри движка mvc в штуке под названием "биндинг" -- и готово.

Comment: Вадим, опишите сценарии как вы собираетесь вмешаться и зачем более подробно. Или вам просто хочется понять механику в общем? Можно просто дать более конкретный ответ, если вы опишите что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: @AK готово, добавил

Comment: Вмешаться я хочу следующим образом:
В серверном объекте переименовать поле Name в ParamName, а java-script объекте оставить как есть.
И заставить мэписться Name в -> ParamName

Answer (score 1):

Ваш javascript объект преобразуется в строку вот тут

```
JSON.stringify(data)
```

и эта строка становится частью асинхронного POST http запроса от браузера на сервер. Этот запрос отправляется асинхронно при помощи функции

```
$.ajax(...)
```

Cервер смотрит на запрос, выбирает нужный контроллер и метод в нем, смотрит какие метод принимает параметры,

```
public class HomeController
{
 .....
   [HttpPost]
   public SearchResult SearchClick(SearchParamsModel p)
   {
     .......
   }
}
```

использует привязки (bindings) чтобы переданный JSON сконвертировать в параметр метода, вызывает метод, получает результат и отправляет его обратно браузеру